# Write a number to FileOutputStream after an offset

Tags: java, offset, fileoutputstream

I want to write a number to the `FileOutputStream` after a certain offset. What I have wrote is the following:

```
String t = Integer.toString(num);
output.write(t.getBytes(), OFFSET, t.length());
```

Is this a good way to do this, or this there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic XY problem. What you want to do is write to a *file* at a specific offset. Specifying 'FileOutputStream' isn't part of the problem, it is part of your incorrect solution. You should be using RandomAccessFile for this task.

Comment: Indeed, RandomAccessFile is better suited for this particular task. He seemed to want to use FileOutputStream, though.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) class correctly. The first parameter is the array you want to write on the file. The second one is the offset from that array that you want to start writing from. The third one is the length of what you want to write. So, in your case, if you use an offset which is different from 0, you'll get an out of bounds exception.

If you want to write that number inside a file using FileOutputStream, you can read that file (using, for example, a [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)), read the amount of bytes you want to read and write them into the output stream, then write that number using something akin to:

```
output.write(t.getBytes(),0,t.length);
```

And finally reading the rest of the inputstream and writing it into the outputstream.

Best of luck.

Comment: Ohh, well what can I use to write after an offset. I want to write a number but not from the start of the file, I want to write it after lets say 5 characters.

Comment: You'll need to read the first 5 characters using FileInputStream (and write them into the fileoutputstream), then write your number, and finally write the rest of what you read from the fileinputstream into the fileoutputstream. See this tutorial for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: Thanks Sirs, I'll look into the tutorial.

Comment: He won't get an exception if he used an offset that is different from zero. That will only happen if the offset *plus the length* is out of bounds. That does happen in this case, but it isn't what you stated. Everything after 'you'll need' is only one of several possible solutions, not a 'need' at all. -1

Comment: I think the "in your case" expression is quite clear. Also, he's explicitly asking for writing a number in a FileOutputStream. I'll just change the "you'll need expression" for "you can".

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that corresponds to the @sirs comment :

```
    final RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    raf.setLength(offset);
    raf.seek(offset);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(raf.getFD()) {
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            raf.close();
        }
    };

    fos.write(myInt);
```